# Is there a way to optimize std algorithms?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, optimization, std

Searching any information about std algorithms performance, I've found [the Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622109/why-is-c-stdmax-element-so-slow) about performance difference between `std::max_element()` and self-written function. I've tested the functions from the question with GCC 9.2.0 and found no performance difference, i.e. `my_max_element_orig()` and `my_max_element_changed()` (from the accepted answer) show the same performance. So it seems like it was just an optimizer issue in GCC 4.8.2. What I really found for GCC 9.2.0 is the significant difference in case I use pointers and iterators - using iterators is about 2 times worse against raw pointers. And there is the similar difference for iterators and raw pointers if using `std::max_element()`.

Let's take `my_max_element_orig` function implementation (see below) and try to run the test.

```
template<typename _ForwardIterator>
_ForwardIterator my_max_element_orig(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
{
  if (__first == __last) return __first;
  _ForwardIterator __result = __first;
  while (++__first != __last)
    if (*__result < *__first)
      __result = __first;
  return __result;
}
```

The following usage example

```
int maxValue = *my_max_element_orig(begin(vec), end(vec));
```

is worse than the following (raw pointers)

```
int maxValue = *my_max_element_orig(vec.data(), vec.data() + vec.size());
```

Someone may say that the reason is that iterator class implementation introduces some overhead. However I found that the reason is the presense of the following line:

```
if (__first == __last) return __first;
```

If the line above is removed from the function, then iterators show the same performance as raw pointers. After some experiments I decided to intervene to the optimizer's branch prediction and replaced the line with the following:

```
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x),0)
...
if (unlikely(__first == __last)) return __first;
```

With the changes above `my_max_element_orig()` function shows the same performance regardless of using iterators or raw pointers. I made the similar change in the `std::max_element()` function from `std_algo.h` file, and got the same results - now `std::max_element()` shows the same performance for both iterators and raw pointers.

The fact is both the original question I linked to and my finding are about "how does GCC optimizer work" or "is it an optimizer issue" questions. However I'd like to use std algorithms, and I don't want to re-write them to get more optimized code. So I'm wondering if there is a way to change branch prediction for `std::max_element()`, like I did it above for my own function. Or more general, is there a way to get std algorithms more optimized without re-writing them?

- GCC 9.2.0
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
- `g++ -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++17`
- Test programs: https://godbolt.org/z/HrABJt

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202404/discussion-on-question-by-rom098-is-there-a-way-to-optimize-std-algorithms).